# Magento 2 How to create a slide-out panel containing product grid?

Tags: magento2, grid

I have displayed my one custom product table in a grid format and there is a button "Add Featured Products".

[image]

How can I make the button to display a slide-out panel containing another grid?
It's just like the functionality in "Edit Product" -> "Configuration" -> "Add Products Manually"

[image]

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: @priyank
Have you ever got any solutions for this? I am looking for the same thing but not able to show the grid in the slide-out modal.